# How could I set up a GM/admin NO-REPLY Email account on AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I regiested my doamin on route53 and also enable the SES,

However, I don't how to set up a system email eg: admin@mycom.com to send system mails to user.

Because I couldn't use a non-verified email account to be a sender.

But I don't know how to create a new email account that might look like admin@xxx sys@xxx under my current domain and make it verified by SES.

[image: inline]
[image: inline]
[image: inline]

Comment: For getting that email for your domain you will have to setup a email box with some service provider you can use google https://apps.google.com/products/gmail/ and then verify that email to be used with SES.

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to do here ? Till the time you are in sandbox mode you need to verify the account to which you can SEND email from your mycom.com account. You do not need to verify any mycom.com account for this.